# Element UI file upload compare filetype

Tags: vue.js, element

It should only allow png, jpg, jpeg, bmp file type.

How can we do that using element ui **`vuejs`**

```
beforeAvatarUpload(file) {
    const isJPG = file.type === 'image/jpeg' || 'image/png';
    const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;

    if (!isJPG) {
        this.$message.error('Avatar picture must be JPG format!');
    }

    if (!isLt2M) {
        this.$message.error('Avatar picture size can not exceed 2MB!');
    }

    return isJPG && isLt2M;
}
```

Does not work for me. Also it does not display me msword type in windows system. Don't know why 

 Please guide 
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only allow jpg or png image types you can write the below code. You don't need to check the type of the image (explicitly).

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg || image/png">
```

In accept attribute whatever the types you mention those kind of images only user can upload. In above if you mention only jpeg or png user can upload specified type of image only.

If you only want jpg then you can write like this.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg"> //
```

Comment: No this is not a solution this will not stop user to check validation

Comment: I have tried it. I mentioned jpg in accept attribute and try to upload png. It worked in firefox.